# automatic authentication with svn and git

Tags: git, svn

I don't want to have to enter my username and password every time I push etc. How does one setup automatic authentication for svn and git? Can one use gnome-keyring?

Comment: For git, you just need to set up SSH. There is a guide by GitHub at https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/ but it is written in a general fashion and applies to any repo hosting service.

Comment: U wanna 2 read bukz

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding git global configs. To setup it, use this command.

> git config --global --edit

Then it open *.gitconfig* file, you have to update file as follow.

```
[user]
    name = <github username>
    email = <github email>
    pass = <github password>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this looks like the password is in plaintext on my computer. Is there a better way?

Comment: This .gitconfig file is a hidden file. So you can use this safely.

Comment: But anyone with access to my machine has access to this file.

Comment: Yes. This will be a problem.